# Why is my javascript not functioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a layout from Codepen: http://codepen.io/trhino/pen/ytoqv

and I have put certain parts of that code into my html but it is not functioning. Can anybody tell me why and what I can do to fix it? All I want from the codepen tutorial is the actual image gallery effect and the 'click to expand' and 'collapse' buttons.

Here is what my site looks like at the minute (ignore the stretched photos, I will be correcting this once I have sorted the javascript)

http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/photo.html

Really appreciate ANY help! This is my code:

```
    <h2>(click on the box to expand gallery)</h2>


<div class="wrap">
  <div id="picture1" class="deck"> 
      <img src="http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/gallery/newyork1.JPG">
      </a>
    </div>
  <div id="picture2" class="deck">
      <img src="http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/gallery/newyork2.JPG">
      </a></div>
  <div id="picture3" class="deck"> 
      <img src="http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/gallery/newyork3.JPG">
      </a></div>
  <div id="picture4" class="deck">
      <img src="http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/gallery/newyork4.JPG">
      </a></div>
  <div id="picture5" class="deck">
      <img src="http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/gallery/newyork5.JPG">
      </a></div>
</div>


      <div id="close"><p>&laquo; collapse gallery</p></div>


  <div id="lightbox">
<div id="lightwrap">
 <div id="x"></div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
    /* gallery */

*, *::before, *::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #6CBDEB;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 1125px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.deck {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #FADBC8;
  height: 202px;
  width: 202px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height:200px;
  text-align: center;

}

.deck a {
  color: black;
}

.deck img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.album {
  border: 1px solid #FADBC8;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative;
}

#close {
  position: relative;
  display: none;  
  width: 1125px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
}

#close p {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 20px 0;
}
#lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
}

#lightwrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  top: 15%;
  display: table;
}

#lightwrap img {
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 600px;
}

#x {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABsAAAAbCAMAAAC6CgRnAAAAPFBMVEX///8AAAD9/f2CgoKAgIAAAAAAAAAAAABLS0sAAAAAAACqqqqqqqq6urpKSkpISEgAAAC7u7u5ubn////zbsMcAAAAE3RSTlMASv6rqwAWS5YMC7/AyZWVFcrJCYaKfAAAAHhJREFUeF590kkOgCAQRFEaFVGc+/53FYmbz6JqBbyQMFSYuoQuV+iTflnstI7ssLXRvMWRaEMs84e2uVckuZe6knL0hiSPObXhj6ChzoEkIolIIpKIO4joICAIeDd7QGIfCCjOKe9HEk8mnxpIAup/F31RPZP9fAG3IAyBSJe0igAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and this is the Javascript:

```
 var i, expand = false;

function reset() {
  $('.deck').css({
    'transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
    'top'      : '0px'
  });
}

//expands and contracts deck on click
$('.deck').click(function (a) {
  if (expand) {
    a.preventDefault();
    var imgSource = $(this).children().attr('href');
    $('#lightwrap').append('<img src="' + imgSource + '" id="lb-pic">');
    $('#lightbox, #lightwrap').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    var boxWidth = $('.deck').width();
    $('.deck').each(function (e) {
      $(this).css({
        'left': boxWidth * e * 1.1 + 'px'
      });
      expand = true;
      $('#close').show();
    });
  }
});

//close lightbox
$('#x, #lightbox').click(function(){
  $('#lightbox').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#lightwrap').hide();
  $('#lb-pic').remove();
});

//prevent event bubbling on lightbox child
$('#lightwrap').click(function(b) {
  b.stopPropagation();
});

$('#close').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('.deck').css({'left': '0px'});
  expand = false;
});

$('.deck:last-child').hover(
  //random image rotation 
  function() {
    if (expand === false) {    
      $('.deck').each(function () {
        i++;
        if (i < $('.deck').length) {
          var min = -30,
              max = 30,
              random = ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
          $(this).css({
            'transform' : 'rotate(' + random + 'deg)',
            'top'       : random + 15 + 'px'
          });
        }
      });
    }
  //straightens out deck images when clicked
  $('.deck').click(
    function (a) {
      a.preventDefault();
      reset();
    }); 
  },
  //undo image rotation when not hovered
  function () {
    i = 0;
    reset();
  }
);
```

Comment: If you want to debug it yourself, type `debugger;` anywhere you'd like to place a break point. After that, refresh your page(don't click any pictures), hit f12(if on chrome), then click a picture. And debug like any other program(assuming you know how to debug a program).

Comment: Note that on each hover, a new click handler is attached to each `.deck`

Comment: I'm a beginner html and do my validation at the end and go back, cheers for the confidence you internet trolls. @pluto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just enclose your javascript in a `$( document ).ready()` [function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) in order to execute on load of the page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //paste javascript code here
});
```

The Result will be this:

[image]

Here is also a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/hayawenodo/1/edit) for it

Comment: Thank you so much, something so simple yet important! Thank you for your helpful answer, much nicer to read that other degrading comments